# Installing Symfony 1.4 with Postgres in Mac OSX 10.6

Tags: postgresql, symfony1, schema, installation

I tried following the tutorial in this site. http://geek-madness.blogspot.com/2010/12/using-postgresql-with-symfony-14.html but was not successful in running my application in symfony. I always get the following error whenever I insert the sql on my database in postgre.

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in ../plugins/sfPostgresDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Export/Pgsql.php on line 449
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near

Can someone help me with this problem. I have Postgre 8.4 Apache 5.3 and PHP 5.3

Answer (score 1):

I thing that problem is in generated sql, if this is not a problem send me the schema.yml file, if this is a bug in sfPostgresDoctrinePlugin I will fix it.